# how to make changes in empty spaces in csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, null

I am working with a huge csv file. I am trying to multiply the columns but it wont let me do it since there are a lot of empty cells. So basically what I am trying to do is write an if else statement where if the cell is empty than that cell copy's the value above it and if there is no value above it (like in row 1 where the only value above it is the header) it should just write 0 (zero). What I mainly need help in is structuring the if else statement.

[This is the screenshot of DataFrame I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwnr0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each column in your dataframe, use `fillna` method to replace the values of `None` cells with the value of the previous row in that columns. For the first row in the column, you can assign that 0 manually. What I said can be done by doing the following:

```
for col in list(df):
    df[col].fillna( method ='ffill', inplace = True)
    if(df[col][0] == None):
        df[col][0] = 0
```

Comment: thanks.  Is there a way to fill zeros in all the empty cells in first row. also is there a way to put the zero only on selected columns of the first row. I mainly want to do the latter

Comment: Actually you can do that with the given code, just create a list of the desired columns which you want to put 0 on the first row if null and modify the if condition to `if(df[col][0] == None && col in desiredColumnList):`

Comment: @Rookie18, if this answers your query, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer

Answer (score 0):

To do it on all columns at once you can `ffill` and then `fillna`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None, 1, None], 'b': [2, None, None]})
df.ffill().fillna(0)
```

gives

```
     a    b
0  0.0  2.0
1  1.0  2.0
2  1.0  2.0
```